# how to show android videoview full area of view/layout?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, android-fullscreen

I am try to play video in android. I am able to play videos but the problem is that despite of setting match_parent height to video view it will not showing in full view. It shows like below in both the orientation. anyone know kindly help me to play in area of video view.

[image]

[image]

Below is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.example.icabmedia.CustomVideoView android:id="@+id/custom_videoview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/img_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:visibility="gone"></GridView></LinearLayout>
```

Configchange method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        img_grid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d("TAG", "landscape");
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        img_grid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d("TAG","Portrait");
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing the weight of videoview .

Comment: @W4R10CK I have tried by removing the weight of videoview but it won't work.